# Is there a way to determine whether a CloseHandle() is last for a named object?

Tags: windows, resources

When creating a named object in windows, one can find out if the object already exists, by calling `GetLastError()` and checking for `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

Is there a way to ask the dual question: is my `CloseHandle()` the last to close (the handle to) a named resource?

Comment: Did you mean: can I find out whether my CloseHandle() closed the last handle to the named resource in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly, no.

<strike>However, you can get it *indirectly* by calling [GetHandleInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724329%28VS.85%29.aspx) after `CloseHandle`. If the handle is not valid, the function will fail and set the error number to`ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.</strike>

And no, not indirectly either, thinking about it again. This will only tell you that your handle is invalid... which you already know since you closed it.

Answer (score 2):

No, [kernel handles aren't reference-counted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/29/4620336.aspx). When you call `CloseHandle`, that closes the handle.